# Save uploaded file through custom controller

Tags: customer, controllers, forms, upload

My code with file path is as follows:
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sean_customdocuments/form.phtml
I have a form on this page,

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customdocuments/index/send') ?>">
    <h2>Upload Seller's Permit Here:</h2>
    <input type="file" name="sellerPermit" id="sellerPermit">
    <input class="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Upload Documents" name="submit">
</form>
```

That form correctly sends the file to my custom controller
app/code/local/Sean/CustomDocuments/controllers/indexController.php

```
<?php
class Sean_CustomDocuments_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function indexAction(){ //this will display the form
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('core/session'); //this will allow flash messages
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
    public function sendAction(){ //handles the form submit
        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        $post = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
        $info = pathinfo('/media/custom_documents/seller_permits/' . $post['seller_permit']);
        $ext = $info['extension'];
        $filename = $post['seller_permit'] . $ext;

        $target = '/media/custom_documents/seller_permits' . $filename;
        move_uploaded_file($post['sellerPermit'], $target);

        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($this->__('Your Documents have been updated!'));//add success message.
        $this->_redirect('*/*');
    }
}
```

media is on the same directory level as app
I want to save the files customers are uploading through my form to
media/custom_documents/seller_permits

But it's not working does anyone have any idea why?
The correct stuff is getting to the controller I'm just having trouble saving it as a file to my target directory.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are missing form attribute "**enctype="multipart/form-data"**

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customdocuments/index/send') ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

You can try with this code.